# Access pivotParent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have 3 tables :

- langs : id (PK) , langname
- lang_sector : lang_id (FK) , sector_id (FK) , sectorname ....
- sectors : id (PK)

Here are the relations in Lang model

```
public function sectors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sector')
        ->withPivot('sectname','sectshortname','sectdescription','sectshortdescription')
        ->whereNull('lang_sector.deleted_at')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Here are the relations in Sector model

```
public function langs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')
        ->withPivot('sectname','sectshortname','sectdescription','sectshortdescription')
        ->whereNull('lang_sector.deleted_at')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I create an index method

```
public function index() {
    $countLang = Lang::count();
    $countSector = Sector::count();
    $admins = Admin::all();
    for ($i=1; $i<=$countLang; $i++) {
        $langs = Lang::find($i);
        $sectors[$i] = $langs->sectors()->get();
    }
    return view('admin.sectors.index', compact('admins', 'sectors', 'langs', 'countLang', 'countSector'));
}
```

In my front I have to reach for each sector, the langname which is in the lang table ... When I use the dd() method in the view

```
@foreach ($sectors as $sector)
    @for($i=0; $i < $countSector; $i++)
        {{ dd($sector[$i]->pivot) }}
    @endfor
@endforeach
```

I obtain those result (abstract) :

```
Pivot {#684 ▼
  +pivotParent: Lang {#636 ▼
    #table: "langs"
    #fillable: array:2 [▼
      0 => "langname"
      1 => "langisocode"
    ]
    ....
    #attributes: array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "langname" => "Français"
      "langisocode" => "fr-FR"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-06 08:19:24"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-07 18:56:21"
      "deleted_at" => null
      ...
    ]
    #original: array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "langname" => "Français"
      ...
    ]
    ....
    }
    #foreignKey: "lang_id"
    #relatedKey: "sector_id"
    #table: "lang_sector"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    ....
    #attributes: array:8 [▼
      "lang_id" => 1
      "sector_id" => 1
      "sectname" => "Technologies de l'information et de la Communication"
      "sectshortname" => "TIC"
      "sectdescription" => "description TIC"
      "sectshortdescription" => "description TIC courte"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-07 21:41:10"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-07 21:41:10"
    ]
    ....
    }
```

It means that i can surelly reach the langs table and its columns... The question is "how can i do it" ...

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i rewrote my sql request ... What i want to diplay is the result of this request :

```
SELECT
    sectors.*,
    lang_sector.*,
    langs.*
FROM sectors
    INNER JOIN lang_sector ON sectors.id = lang_sector.sector_id
    INNER JOIN langs ON lang_sector.lang_id = langs.id;
```

So i decided to use query builder :

```
$sectors = DB::table('sectors')
    ->join('lang_sector','sectors.id','=','lang_sector.sector_id')
    ->join('langs','lang_sector.lang_id','=','langs.id')
    ->select('langs.*', 'lang_sector.*', 'sectors.*')
    ->get();
```

Then in my view i don't have to use any pivot stuff 
and just have to write this way :

```
@foreach($sectors as $sector) 
    {{ $sector->anyfieldfromrequest }}
@endforeach
```

Thanks for your answers... Mainly Samuel Loza who shows me the problems encountered by my first request

Answer (score 1):

I see a logic problem
When the ids are continuously, it will work well

```
+-----+------------+
|  id   | langname |
|  1    |   esp    |
|  2    |  esp2    |
|  3    |  esp3    |
+-----+------------+
```

$ countLang = Lang :: count (); //3
The for route from 1 to 3

> ```
> for ($i=1; $i<=$countLang; $i++) {
>         $langs = Lang::find($i);
>         $sectors[$i] = $langs->sectors()->get();
> }
> ```

Here is the error, look at the id's
$countLang = Lang :: count (); //3

```
+-----+------------+
|  id   | langname |
|  1    |  esp     |
|  3    |  esp2    |
|  4    |  esp3    |
+-----+------------+
```

The for will never arrive at id = 4, because in the Lang::count(); is 3

```
Lang :: find (1) ok
Lang :: find (2) error
Lang :: find (3) ok
```

Read the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I read the documentation already ... unfortunatelly i'm stuck here ... I can hope i'll never have to delete a lang in my app ... I try to solve this issue for a rather long time now ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$sector->pivot->fieldName;
```

Comment: Well ... it woud work but in $sector->pivot->fieldname reach the pivot table ... which is not containing the lang name ... I'm going to update my post to show my db structure ...

Comment: Would you provide the relationships code to make it more clear what you want ?

Comment: so you want to know how to access `langname` ?